# Search for Files in Windows by RegEx?

Tags: windows, search, regex, file-search

I want to search a folder on my computer for any file names matching `"???x???.jpg"`.

Where the question marks can be 0-9, but I don't want it to match something like `homxtop.jpg`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes with powershell

```
PS> dir | ?{$_.name -match "^[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3}.jpg$"}
```

Comment: It's missing a parenthesis and could be rewritten as a simple `where name -match "^[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3}.jpg$"` as it is a single condition.

Answer (score 1):

chingNotCHing already supplied a solution based on PowerShell but this one could be slightly faster depending on how many folders you're looking at and it could help if you're looking into a directory structure.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.jpg" | Where name -match "^[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3}.jpg$"
```

What this would do is look recursively for all `*.jpg` starting from your current directory (which would already be a smaller set than a recursive `dir`) and only filter those files for the actual pattern. To just look at the current directory you would drop the `-Recurse` but in that case the simple `dir` method should be more intuitive.

Comment: If you do just up vote it. :D